# Access the content of a php file from Browser direct folder access

Tags: php, apache

I want to see the content of a php file on which I have direct access from browser

**Browser direct folder access:**
[image: Browser direct folder access]

I didn't have any luck finding informations regarding this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant see the PHP code of a PHP file directly from a Web browser.

You must code or use a code editor JS library like: https://ace.c9.io/